# Drupal lightframe / lightboxs not working

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-6, lightbox

This should be an easy one for someone I hope. I have had a Drupal 6 job land with me and I know nothing about it. What I'm trying to do is use an Iframe in a lightbox. I did a bit of a google and come up with somthing but the code editor will not let me do it.

The on-page source editor you get if you go to page->edit->source seems to remove some of the code i put there.

I put in:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="lightframe[|width:400px; height:300px; scrolling: auto;]">Search google</a>
```

and save it. I get no ligthbox, just a link to google. If I go back in to the source editor all I can see is this:

```
<p><a rel=" auto;]" href="http://www.google.com">Search google</a></p>
```

I can get the lightframe to work with just `rel="lightframe"` but I need to resize it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your input format is set to full html, or filtered html. Otherwise, if its not set to this, drupal will filter html code out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh, there's always a simple answer! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to colons in your rel attribute. Check out your issue on the issue tracker [here](http://drupal.org/node/483798#comment-2962356). There is an explanation of how to fix this as well as a patch you can apply.

What's happening is that your rel attribute is essentially being cleaned, or filtered out, likely by security oriented filters (Input scrubbers for example) that are active in your project. You could disable them, but they are likely more useful to you enabled.